# How would I do a loop while selenium connects to a webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, sys

I am trying to make it do a loop while connecting to a webpage via selenium. Here is the code:

```py
from sys.stdout import flush
from sys import argv
from selenium import webdriver
def loading():
    print("Loading.\r")
    flush()
    print("Loading..\r")
    flush()
    print("Loading...\r")
    flush()
driver = mydriverslocation
website = argv[1]
driver.get(website)
# Do loading() while connecting to website
```

So how would I call `loading()` while also connecting to website?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "how would I do loading() while connecting to website?"

Comment: Do you want to print "loading..." to the standard output while the web page is loading in the browser?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes

Comment: You need something asynchronous  like node.js or possibly async_io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do here is parallelism. I know one way, but there may be more efficient ways to do this.

```
import threading
from sys.stdout import flush
from sys import argv
from selenium import webdriver

website_loaded = False

def loading():
    while not website_loaded:
        print("Loading.\r")
        flush()
        print("Loading..\r")
        flush()
        print("Loading...\r")
        flush()

driver = mydriverslocation
website = argv[1]

# Start the loading thread
# Expected method to run, and arguments.
loading_thread = threading.Thread(loading, ())
loading_thread.start()

driver.get(website)
# And any other code while loading

# This will pass to the thread
website_loaded = True
```

Comment: When I run the code, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sys.stdout'; 'sys' is not a package. Do you know how to fix it? I am on windows 10 using python 3.7.4 in case you needed to know

Comment: @TheRealTengri I copied that module from your code. I’m sure you can find a solution somewhere on this site.